# Storing array data into database in one to many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, one-to-many

Hello all I want to add branch to User, I have user model like this :

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :user_branches
end
```

and then I have user controller like this :

```
def create
@user_branches=params[:branch_ids]

params[:user][:password] = params[:user][:username]
@user = User.new(params[:user])
respond_to do |format|
  if @user.save
    # UserBranch.new(branch_id: b[0], user_id: params[:user_id])
     @user_branches.each do |branch|
      @user_branch = UserBranch.new(branch_id: branch, user_id: params[:user_id])
     @user_branch.save
    end

    flash[:notice] = 'Success Add New User'
    format.js
  else
    flash[:error] = @user.errors.full_messages
    format.js#html { render action: "new" }
  end
end
```

The content of `@user_branches` are like this `["2", "3", "4"]`.
Above code work. But `user_id` not inserting.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve with the ids?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`params[:user_id]` how can you get this from `form`?

You are creating the `user` in `create` method.

It should probably be,

`UserBranch.new(branch_id: branch, user_id: @user.id)`